# Log in to Azure AD B2C without redirecting to b2clogin Microsoft page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am building a react application which needs to be sign in and sign up users only through the application. I am using AADB2C for user management. I know this question has been asked several times in the past, but I still finding a way to sign up/sign in users using AADB2C without redirecting to Microsoft login page. I found it impossible back in 2 years ago, but I really appreciate your help, If there is any services or packages to overcome this riddle .

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/21036/log-in-to-azure-ad-b2c-without-redirecting-to-b2cl.html 
Check out this if anyone finding an answer

Answer (score 2):

@PrathapG I have responded to your question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/21036/log-in-to-azure-ad-b2c-without-redirecting-to-b2cl.html

Comment: @PrathapG could you accept this as answer as well? it will help others to find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be some sort of Identity management for your application. if you don't want Microsoft to do the identity management for your application then there are various other options.

[image]

There are several well known Identity Providers like Amazon , Facebook etc
Or you can provide your own Identity provider using the first option
"+New OpenID Connect Provider".

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the Graph API to directly create users into the B2C Directory, but that defeats most of the advantages of B2C of not having to write the plumbing code.

You are now also responsible for securing this user creation code.

Currently the new login url is: .b2clogin.com, which does not contain any reference to MS anymore, which partly may solve your issue?